# How can I use the url from a query for a backgournd?

Tags: reactjs

```
<div style={{background: "url(http://localhost:8000/static/myproject/mypic.jpg)"}}
      className="h-52 sm:h-full sm:w-72 rounded-xl bg-gray-100 bg-center bg-cover"
 />
```

But I would like something like that :

```
<div style={{background: "{todo.mypic}"}}
     className="h-52 sm:h-full sm:w-72 rounded-xl bg-gray-100 bg-center bg-cover"
 />
```

where `{todo.mypic}` is a variable but it does not work.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style={{background: `url(${todo.mypic})`}}/>
```